# Creating a graph with 3 sets of data within each dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a CSV file that contains data as followed, which I've converted into a dataset. The code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        import seaborn as sns
    df = pd.read_csv('MH_12.csv')
    df = df.set_index("Country")

    df2 = df.loc["Colombia", "2005"]
    print(df2.values)

        Dataset2015 = {"Both sex":[ 7.1],
                   "Male" :[10.9],
                   "Female" :[ 3.1]}
    Dataset2010 = {"Both sex":[ 7.0],
                   "Male" :[11.1],
                   "Female" :[ 2.8]}
    Dataset2005 = {"Both sex":[ 7.3],
                   "Male" :[11.7],
                   "Female" :[ 2.6]}
    Dataset2000 = {"Both sex":[ 6.7],
                   "Male" :[10.9],
                   "Female" :[ 2.3]}
```

What I would like to do is convert this into a column graph, with each data set separated by year (2015, 2010, 2005, and 2000), but within those year groups, they have 3 columns of Both sex, Male, and Female. I'm familiar with creating column graphs if the data set only has two sets of data within it (so if this had only both sex, and male, for example).

This is the code I've attempted to use:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(Dataset2015)
df3['year'] = '2015'
df4 = pd.DataFrame(Dataset2010)
df4['year'] = '2010'
df5 = pd.DataFrame(Dataset2005)
df5['year'] = '2005'
df6 = pd.DataFrame(Dataset2000)
df6['year'] = '2000'
df7 = pd.concat([df3,df4,df5,df6])
sns.factorplot(errcolor=".2", edgecolor=".2", data = df, hue='country', x='year', y='Mental Health Issues per 100,000 Population', kind='bar', ci=None, aspect=3, size=7);
plt.title('Mental Health Issues in Colombia')
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
plt.show()
```

I obtain an error, "Year" when running the code, which is understandable. I've left hue as "country", but will change once I figure out how to get this right.

**Question:** How can I create a column graph when each of my data sets contains three points of data?
I have checked the Python API and I could not find a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for 3 columns `DataFrame`:

```
df8 = df7.melt('year', var_name='sex', value_name='a')
print (df8)
    year       sex     a
0   2015  Both sex   7.1
1   2010  Both sex   7.0
2   2005  Both sex   7.3
3   2000  Both sex   6.7
4   2015    Female   3.1
5   2010    Female   2.8
6   2005    Female   2.6
7   2000    Female   2.3
8   2015      Male  10.9
9   2010      Male  11.1
10  2005      Male  11.7
11  2000      Male  10.9

sns.factorplot(errcolor=".2", 
               edgecolor=".2", 
               data = df8, 
               hue='sex', 
               x='year', 
               y='a', 
               kind='bar', 
               ci=None, 
               aspect=3, 
               size=7)
```

Comment: Hi jezreal, that's exactly what I needed. It works perfectly. Thanks again for that! It looks like such a simple process to do!

Comment: @JamesWu - You are welcome! Yes, `melt`working here very nice.